# Is a graph being bipartite an isomorphic variant?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

**Hints only.**

My claim is yes.

Let's say there's two graphs, A and B.

Assuming A is bipartite, A can then be split up into two different graphs a1 and a2. There may be edges between vertices in a1 and a2, but not between members of the same group (no a1 vertice is connected to another vertice in a1).

Isomorphism is a one-to-one and onto function by nature, so every element in A is uniquely related to an element in B. That being said, we can split up graph B into two parts as well - b1 (the set of vertices related to by elements in a1) and b2 ( the set of vertices related to by elements in b2).

Since relationships between vertices are preserved, every element in b1 should therefore be connected only to elements in b2, and not with each other thus making it a bipartite graph.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, it's an isomorphic invariant.  Any property of the graph that only depends on intrinsic properties of the graph structure, and not any particular labeling of its vertices and edges, will be invariant under isomorphism.

Comment: Your proof is correct. I might be a bit more explicit: Let $f:A \rightarrow B$ be a graph isomorphism; then define $b_i$ to be the image of $a_i$ under $f$.  Then explicitly verify the definition of bipartite-ness for $b_1, b_2$: suppose $(x,y)$ is an edge in $B$, show that $x,y$ cannot both be in the same $b_i$.

This is assuming you want a detailed proof.  For a higher-level proof, you could just say "obvious."

Comment: Cheers, mate! I'm working on being as explicit as possible.

Comment: In that case, make sure you explicitly make use of the properties that $f$ is a) one-to-one, b) onto, and c) edge-preserving.  Specifically think about the definition of each of these, not just your intuition about how it should work.  Cheers!